# How to implement security model?

Tags: linux

I have installed Oracle 11g on fedora 14. I connected with SQL*Plus as 'SYS' and
created some tables, then created a user named "account" and a role, "payroll"
with the following privileges. I assigned the role to the "account" user but I 
cannot access the created tables when I log-in as "account".

Here are my queries:

As SYS

```
create type pay_t as object(
id int,
name varchar(10))
/

create table pay of pay_t; 
insert into pay values(pay_t(10,'p01'));

create user account identified by paccount;
grant create session to account;
grant connect to account;

create role pay_roll;
grant select on pay to pay_roll;
grant pay_roll to account;
```

As account:

```
select * from pay;
```

This gives me an error saying there is no such table or view.

Answer (score 2):

The table you created as sys is created in the "sys" schema.

`SELECT` by default accesses the schema of the caller, so in your case, as `SELECT` is run as "account", it tries to access table "pay" in schema "account".

You'll need to either use a schema-prefixed query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.pay
```

Or first create a synonym in "account" schema (as sys):

```
CREATE SYNONYM account.pay FOR sys.pay;
```

You could also use public synonyms, but I would rather not recommend them.

Comment: Also note that creating objects in the SYS schema isn't really a good practice either.